# Symfony | Best way to init property in Entity

Tags: entity, symfony

I'm new in Symfony, i have a question about the best way to init a property in an Entity.

For example, i have an Entity "Question" which has a property "user", i do this :

```
$question = new Question();
$question->setUser($this->getUser());
$form = $this->createForm(QuestionType::class, $question);
```

It works, i can also do it with the constructor :

```
$question = new Question($this->getUser());
$form = $this->createForm(QuestionType::class, $question);
```

It works too but I don't know which one is the best. Or maybe there is another better solution ? I mean, I will have to init this Entity many times and maybe there is a way to do :

```
$question = new Question();
$form = $this->createForm(QuestionType::class, $question);
```

So I don't have to care about "user" in my controllers ?

Anyway, what is the best solution to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether or not a question in your context **must** have a user. If it is optional, the setter is fine - you can create a question even without a user. If it is necessary, you should inject it in the constructor - this also helps other developers and your future self to understand that you cannot create a question without a user.

The third option would mean that you somehow have to fetch the user from inside the question, which couples it to the mechanism that is responsible for that (for example the security component). This is generally a bad idea as it limits it's usages and makes testing a lot harder.

Another hint: maybe `setUser()` is not a good naming choice for a Question class, as it lacks expression of what it really is. Is it the author of the question? Then `setAuthor()` could be a better choice.

Comment: Clear answer and thanks for the hint Daniel, i will change the name of the property.